# Use regular expressions to match Java lambda calls but it doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression to match the following lambda call.

```
Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> ...)
        .isInstanceOf(ValidationException.class);
```

I wrote it like `Assertions\.assertThatExceptionOfType\(.*\)\.isThrownBy\(.*\);`

I use `.*` to match all characters in the function.

But it can't match the lambda call above correctly, how should I modify it to match?

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately regular expressions can't do nested parenthesis (`()`).  You'll have to use a parser or some other method.  If the expression in the parenthesis is always simple there's a chance you could match it, but we'd need more information.

Comment: Regular expressions - that is not just some random term. It refers to the idea that RE's can be used to parse __Regular__ grammars. Which is a specific, well defined concept. Java, the language, __is not regular__. Hence, you can't parse it with regexes. Find another way.

Comment: Why would you want to parse Java with regex? What is the original purpose?

Comment: I don't think the example is a "streaming call" for any standard use of that term.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the methods names with anything in between the parenthesis, this regex works for me :

```
assertThat("Assertions.assertThatThrownBy(() -> xwcsd)\n" +
                "        .isInstanceOf(qscq);", matchesPattern("Assertions\\.assertThatThrownBy\\(.*\\)\\s*\\.isInstanceOf\\(.*\\);"));
```